# Android: Issue using the SAX parser on different Android releases

Tags: android, compatibility, sax

I'm having a problem using the SAX parser to parse a very simple XML file on different Android releases.

Using a Motorola XT316 with Android 2.3.3 the code works fine. I can see that it enters on all the tags. But when using a PanDigital with Android 2.1 the code doesn't work. It opens the XML file correctly but it doesn't enter in any tags.

The code of the parser:

```
 public MyParser(Context context ) {
    super();
    theContext=context;     
    getData();
}
//start of the XML document
@Override
public void startDocument () { 
    Log.d("DataHandler", "Start of XML document");  
}

//end of the XML document
@Override
public void endDocument () { Log.d("DataHandler", "End of XML document"); }

//opening element tag
@Override
public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
{
    if(qName.equals("ARQUIVO"))
    {
        Log.d("DataHandler", "Start of ARQUIVO");                           
    }   
}

//closing element tag
@Override
public void endElement (String uri, String name, String qName)
{       
    if(qName.equals("ARQUIVO"))
    {           
        Log.d("DataHandler", "End of ARQUIVO");
    }       
}

//element content
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length)
{

}

public void getData()
{
    //take care of SAX, input and parsing errors
    try
    {           
        //set the parsing driver
        System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");

        //create a parser
        SAXParserFactory parseFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        parseFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);           
        SAXParser xmlParser = parseFactory.newSAXParser();

        //get an XML reader
        XMLReader xmlIn = xmlParser.getXMLReader();

        //instruct the app to use this object as the handler
        xmlIn.setContentHandler(this);

        InputStreamReader xmlStream = new InputStreamReader(theContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.arquivos));
        //build a buffered reader
        BufferedReader xmlBuff = new BufferedReader(xmlStream);   

        xmlIn.parse(new InputSource(xmlBuff));          
    }
    catch(SAXException se) { 
        Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity","SAX Error " + se.getMessage());           
        }
    catch(IOException ie) { 
        Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity","Input Error " + ie.getMessage());         
    }
    catch(Exception oe) { 
        Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity","Unspecified Error " + oe.getMessage());           
    }       
}
```

}

The XML file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ARQUIVOS>
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/screen.xml"
    arquivo_nome="screen.xml" />
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/Images/T_0.png"
    arquivo_nome="T_0.png" />
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/Images/T_1.png"
    arquivo_nome="T_1.png" />
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/Images/T_2.png"
    arquivo_nome="T_2.png" />
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/Images/T_3.png"
    arquivo_nome="T_3.png" />
<ARQUIVO
    arquivo_caminho="http://192.168.0.60:8099/Images/T_4.png"
    arquivo_nome="T_4.png" />
  </ARQUIVOS>
```

I can see it shows the message "Start of XML document" and "End of XML document" but it doesn't show the message "Start of ARQUIVO" and "End of ARQUIVO" between them.

I don't know why this is happening and can't fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is qName equals when startElement calls? Or it does not calls at all?

Comment: Its on the code, its qName.equals("ARQUIVO")

Comment: so that enter this block   if(qName.equals("ARQUIVO"))
    {
        Log.d("DataHandler", "Start of ARQUIVO");                           
    } , but does not show log message?

Comment: on android 2.3 it shows the message "Start of ARQUIVO" correctly, but on android 2.1 it does not show the message .

Comment: too bad there were not any answers but after a long research i found this link that helped me to solve the problem https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link helped me to solve the problem  code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11223

Apparently there is a difference on the of functionality on the SAX parser between android 2.1 and the newer versions. It puts the tag of the element on different parameters. I don't know if it is a bug but it certainly looks like one.

The way to make it work is to change the functions startElement and endElement.The are implemented below.

```
public static String getCorrectName(String qName, String name) {//used to fix bug from the sax on version 2.1
    String _retValue = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=7) _retValue = localName;
    else _retValue = qName;

    return _retValue;
}
 //opening element tag
 @Override
 public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
{
String corretcName=getCorrectName(qName, name);
if(corretcName.equals("ARQUIVO"))
{
    Log.d("DataHandler", "Start of ARQUIVO");                           
}   
}
//closing element tag
 @Override
 public void endElement (String uri, String name, String qName)
{       
String corretcName=getCorrectName(qName, name);
if(corretcName.equals("ARQUIVO"))
{           
    Log.d("DataHandler", "End of ARQUIVO");
}       
}
```